# Nested VBA collection of classes returning "Argument not optional" error

Tags: vba, class

I am trying to represent the idea of nested classes with collections of child classes with the natural example of Grandmother - Married Daughters - Little kids case, so I have 3 classes as following:

' Class GrandMother:

```
Private pMarriedDaughter As Collection    
Public Property Get MarriedDaughter() As Collection
 MarriedDaughter = pMarriedDaughter
 End Property
Public Property Set MarriedDaughter(C As Collection)
 Set pMarriedDaughter = C
 End Property
```

' Class MarriedMom:

```
Private pChildren As Collection   
Public Property Get Children() As Collection   ' ERROR HERE!
 Children = pChildren
End Property  
Public Property Set Children(C As Collection)
 Set pChildren = C
End Property
```

' Child Class:

```
Private pName As String    
Public Property Get Name() As String
 Name = pName
End Property    
Public Property Let Name(s As String)
 Let pName = s
End Property
```

And the Main Routine that tries to populate the classes:

```
Sub TestGrandMother()

' Create 3 Childs
Dim Child_1a As New Child: Child_1a.Name = "Bill"
Dim Child_1b As New Child: Child_1b.Name = "Sam"
Dim Child_2a As New Child: Child_2a.Name = "Sahar"

' Create 2 Married Daughters:
Dim Mamy1 As New MarriedMom
Dim Mamy2 As New MarriedMom

' Add the the children to the married daughters
Set Mamy1.Children = New Collection
Mamy1.Children.Add Child_1a
Mamy1.Children.Add Child_1b

Set Mamy2.Children = New Collection
Mamy2.Children.Add Child_2a

' Create Grandmother
Dim GrandMa As GrandMother: Set GrandMa = New GrandMother
Set GrandMa.MarriedDaughter = New Collection
GrandMa.MarriedDaughter.Add Mamy1
GrandMa.MarriedDaughter.Add Mamy2

' Now cycle childs Name and debug:
Dim aChild As New Child
For Each aChild In GrandMa.MarriedDaughter.Children
 Debug.Print GrandMa.MarriedDaughter.Children.Name
Next aChild

End Sub
```

Comment: and your question is??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In both cases where that error occurs you need to use the `Set` keyword as working with an object. That is just for the error type you comment on.

e.g.

```
Set Children = pChildren
Set MarriedDaughter = pMarriedDaughter
```

---

The following `GrandMa.MarriedDaughter` does not expose a `.Children` btw.

Perhaps

```
Dim aChild As MarriedMom, nextChild As Child   
For Each aChild In GrandMa.MarriedDaughter
    For Each nextChild In aChild.Children
        Debug.Print nextChild.Name
    Next
Next aChild
```